# Spring Boot Actuator /env endpoint returning data as XML - why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have several Spring Boot apps running as microservices.  Each of them are running spring boot actuator to allow us to monitor /metrics, /env, /health, etc.  On just one of these services the /env endpoint is returning data as XML when requested in the browser.  Further, the XML is invalid, but what I really care about is getting the endpoint to return data in json. The reason the XML is invalid is because we are using Spring Cloud Config and the first element contains the GitHub URL which makes it invalid.

```
<LinkedHashMap xmlns=""><profiles>development</profiles><configService:https://github.com/ourcompany/configs/usage.yml>
```

I can not find anything different about this one project that would allow the data to be returned in json.

If I use cURL and pass an Accept header with value = application/json the service will correctly return json, but why is the browser returning XML?  What I also noticed with this service is that I can pass Accept = application/xml and get it to return XML, but my other services return a 406 Not Acceptable response when requesting XML.  Strange.

We are using spring-boot-starter-parent version 1.2.2.RELEASE as well as using spring-cloud-starter 1.0.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Noticed just after posting that if I request /env.json I can get the data in json, so this will likely solve the problem, but it still begs the question, why does this one service allow XML to be returned but the others return a 406?

Comment: Any chance you have `jackson-dataformat-xml` in the dependencies? If it's available an `XmlMapper` will be autoconfigured. Or an `@XmlRootElement` annotation on your returned object, in which case JAXB might be used.

Answer (score 4):

ci_'s comment above is what is happening.  Having an XmlMapper caused the actuator endpoints to return XML.  Hitting the /env.json endpoint will solve the issue for me.