# XML response of spring actuator/health to JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

By Default in spring boot if we hit the /actuator/health url we get the health in JSON format. But i am using jackson-dataformat-xml for my other api's in the application which makes the health url to change the response format to XML. Is there anyway we can tell spring to respond with JSON for the health url ? I do not want to add my own health url.

This question is asked sometimes before [Spring Boot Actuator /env endpoint returning data as XML - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969626/spring-boot-actuator-env-endpoint-returning-data-as-xml-why)

But did not say a good solution .

Answer (score 1):

You might try to define an `ObjectMapper` bean which takes precedence over the `XmlMapper` bean via [`@Primary`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html):

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
}
```

Comment: @Ids, But this probebly override the XML response mapping right ? Is it possoble to make it only applicable for the actuator/health url. My default mapping is actually XML and i dont want to change that , except for the health

Comment: If you need more control over this you might try [this workaround](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2449) of using a  `EndpointHandlerMappingCustomizer` and limit `preHandle` to operate on requests with urls of a certain pattern.

Comment: This works only in the old spring boot 1.X . This class is removed in the newer version of spring boot

Comment: Can't reproduce it with Spring Boot 2.2.1.

Comment: No, the actuator endpoint returns JSON despite having jackson-dataformat-xml in the classpath.